# When Jensen's inequality is equality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, jensen-inequality

One form of Jensen's inequality is

> If $X$ is a random variable and $g$ is a convex function, then
>   $\mathbb{E}(g(X))\geq g(\mathbb{E}(X))$.

Just out of curiosity, when do we have equality? If and only if $g$ is constant?

Comment: Also if $g$ is affine.

Comment: And/or $X$ constant almost surely.

Comment: I think an if and only if condition would be: there is equality iff there exists an interval A such that g is affine on A, and X belongs to A almost surely.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160095/convexity-and-equality-in-jensen-inequality

Comment: An example of X being constant almost surely is KL(p||q)=0 iff p=q almost surely. Here g is -ln() so can't be affine. The constant must be one (almost surely) due to normalization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for the sake of having an "answered" question (thanks to @hardmath and @Did), Jensen's inequality is equality when $g$ is affine or $X$ is constant almost surely.