# Under what conditions does Jensen's inequality hold with equality?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

From what I understand Jensen's Inequality is

> $$E(f(X))\leq f(E(X)) \;\text{ when $f$ is a concave function}$$

Are there any conditions on the distribution of $X$ (rather than the function f) under which this holds with equality: $E(f(X))=f(E(X))$? (eg. when $VAR(X)=0$, $X$ is a constant so it should hold with equality)

Also, is there any term $O$ which would make this true: $E(f(X)) = f(E(x)) + O $
(I was thinking some sort of Taylor Expansion)

I am mainly interested in the case $f(x)=ln(x)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convexity and equality in Jensen inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160095/convexity-and-equality-in-jensen-inequality)

Comment: I am mainly trying to show that E(ln(X))=E(ln(Y)) does not imply ln(E(X))=ln(E(Y)) and was wondering under which distribitutions of X and Y this was true (my intuition was that if X and Y have different distributions the O term would be different)