# For i.i.d. $\{X_n\}$ with non-constant $X_n > 0$ and $\mathbb{E}X_n = q \leq 1$ the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n \to 0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is i.i.d. with $X_n > 0$ and each $X_n$ is not constant almost surely.

I want to show that if $\mathbb{E}X_n = q \leq 1$, then the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n \to 0$ almost surely. In the problem statement, there is also a hint that $q < 1$ and $q = 1$ can be considered separately.

I thought about this one for a long time and I think applying logarithm operation to both sides and transform this product into a sum might help, but I couldn't progress from there. I'm still unable to see how I can reduce this problem to using laws of large numbers.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: @GEdgar The problem is that I need to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \ln{X_n} \to -\infty$ when all the laws of large numbers I know would be about convergence of $\dfrac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\ln{X_n} \to 0$ when $N \to +\infty$

Comment: @GEdgar Of course, that was a typo on my side. What I don't understand is how it's going to help to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \ln{X_n} \to -\infty$ (which is an equivalent form of what needs to be proved in this problem).

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed, because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N t_n \sim N\mu$ asymptotically. I got it now! I wonder what happens when $\mu = 0$?

Comment: Use $X_n$ is not constant to prove $\mu < 0$.

Comment: Are you familiar with martingales? In the case $q=1$, it may be helpful to note that $M_n:=\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$ is a positive martingale.

Comment: @GEdgar Is that true? If $X_n$ is, for example, 1/2 or 3/2, both with probabilities 1/2, then $EX_n=1$ and $\ln E(X_1) = 0$.

Comment: @Jason No, I'm not. Maybe there's a more elementary proof?

Comment: In that case proceed with @GEdgar's advice. Note that $\mu = \mathbb E[\log X_1]$. Use Jensen's inequality to compare this to $\log\mathbb E[X_1]$. Then use the fact that $X_1$ is not constant and your knowledge of when Jensen's inequality is an equality.

Comment: @Jason Thank you! But didn't I present a counterexample to GEdgar comment?

Comment: @Jason Of course, it wasn't a counterexample. Thank you, everything worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_{n}>0$, we have that $q=E[X_{n}]>0$. Define the process
$M=\{M_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ by $M_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{X_{k}}{q}.$
Let $\mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be the raw-filtration
induced by $M,$ i.e., $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma\{M_{1},M_{2},\ldots,M_{n}\}$.
Note that we also have $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma\{X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\}.$
We go to show that $M$ is a $L^{1}$-bounded $\mathbb{F}$-martingale.
Clearly $M_{n}$ is integrable (recall that the product of two independent
random variables is integrable). Moreover, since $X_{n+1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{n}$
are independent while $M_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable, we
have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & E\left[M_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[\frac{X_{n+1}}{q}M_{n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & M_{n}E\left[\frac{X_{n+1}}{q}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & M_{n}E\left[\frac{X_{n+1}}{q}\right]\\
 & = & M_{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Moreover, since $M_{n}>0$, we clearly have $E\left[|M_{n}|\right]=E\left[M_{n}\right]=E[M_{1}]=E[X{}_{1}/q]=1$.
This shows that $\sup_{n}E\left[|M_{n}|\right]<\infty.$

By Martingale Convergence Theorem, there exists a $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$-measurable
random variable $\xi$ with $E[|\xi|]<\infty$ such that $M_{n}\rightarrow\xi$
pointwisely a.e. (Note that, in general, we do not have $M_{n}\rightarrow\xi$
in $L^{1}$).

Case 1: $q<1$. We have that $\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{n}=q^{n}M_{n}\rightarrow0$
a.e. because $q^{n}\rightarrow0$ while $M_{n}\rightarrow\xi$ a.e.

Case 2: Define $a=E\left[\sqrt{X_{n}}\right].$ By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
a & = & \int\sqrt{X_{n}}\cdot1dP\\
 & \leq & \left\{ \int X_{n}dP\right\} ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left\{ \int1^{2}dP\right\} ^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
 & = & 1
\end{eqnarray*}
and the equality holds iff $\sqrt{X_{n}}$ and $1$ are linearly dependent (as elements in $L^2$, which is false since $X_{n}$ is not constant a.e.). Therefore, $0<a<1.$

Define a process $Y=\{Y_{n},\,\,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ by $Y_{n}=\frac{\sqrt{M_{n}}}{a^{n}}.$
It can be proved similarly that $Y$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-martingale.
For, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $M_{n}$ is integrable $\Rightarrow$
$\sqrt{M_{n}}$ is integrable. Clearly $Y_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable.
Moreover,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & E\left[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & E\left[\frac{\sqrt{X_{n+1}}}{a}\cdot Y_{n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & Y_{n}E\left[\frac{\sqrt{X_{n+1}}}{a}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & Y_{n}E\left[\frac{\sqrt{X_{n+1}}}{a}\right]\\
 & = & Y_{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $Y$ is non-negative, we have that $E\left[|Y_{n}|\right]=E\left[Y_{n}\right]=E\left[Y_{1}\right].$
It follows that $\sup_{n}E\left[|Y_{n}|\right]<\infty$, i.e., $Y$
is $L^{1}$-bounded. By Martingale Convergence Theorem again, there
exists an **integrable** random variable $\eta$ such that $Y_{n}\rightarrow\eta$
a.e.. Recall that $M_{n}\rightarrow\xi$ a.e. and notice that $M_{n}=a^{2n}Y_{n}^{2}$.
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have that $\xi=0$ a.e. because
$a^{2n}\rightarrow0$ while $Y_{n}^{2}\rightarrow\eta^{2}<\infty$
a.e.

Comment: The OP had stated they are not familiar with martingales.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my first hasty attempt, perhaps this will be more satisfactory. As you noted, the problem is equivalent to showing that $\sum_i \log(X_i) = -\infty$ a.s.

Firstly, since the logarithm is concave and not affine and $X_i$ is not a.s. constant, one has by Jensen's inequality that

$$0 = \log(1) \geq \log q = \log(E[X_i]) > E[\log(X_i)] := \mu.$$

You can see, e.g. [Convexity and equality in Jensen inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160095/convexity-and-equality-in-jensen-inequality) for when Jensen's inequality can be an equality. In our case, it must be strict inequality, which we used in the previous line.

Thus it suffices to show (set $Y_i := -\log(X_i)$) the following:

**Theorem.**  If $Y_i$ are iid with $\mu := E[Y_i] > 0$, then $\sum_i Y_i = \infty$ a.s.

**Lemma.** For any real valued $(y_i)_i$, if $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \to \mu > 0$ then $\sum_i y_i = \infty$.

**Proof of lemma.** Let any subsequence $n_k \to \infty$ be given.
Then $$\sum_{i=0}^{n_k} y_i =(\frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i=0}^{n_k} y_i) n_k \to \mu \times \infty = \infty.$$ In particular this shows $\liminf_n \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i = \infty$, so $\sum_i y_i = \infty$. QED.

**Proof of theorem.** If $\mu < \infty$ then by the law of large numbers $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i \to \mu >0$ a.s.
By the lemma, $\sum_i Y_i = \infty$ a.s. in this case.

Now consider the case $\mu = \infty$. Considering that $E[Y_i] > -\infty$ and writing $Y_i = Y_i^+ - Y_i^-$ with $Y_i^+ = \max(Y_i, 0)$ and $Y_i^-= \max(-Y_i, 0)$ the usual decomposition of $Y_i$ into its positive and negative parts, it must be that $E[Y_i^-] \in [0,\infty)$ and $E[Y_i^+] = \infty$.
In particular
$$
E[\max(Y_i, n)] = E[\max(Y_i^+,n) - Y_i^-] =  E[\max(Y_i^+,n)] - E[Y_i^-] \to \infty
$$
by monotone convergence of $\max(Y_i^+,n) \to Y_i^+$. In particular we may choose $N$ large enough that $0 < E[\max(Y_i, N)] \leq N$. The random variables $(\max(Y_i, N))_i$ are iid with mean in $(0,\infty)$,  so by what we showed earlier $\sum_i \max(Y_i, N) = \infty$ a.s. Then it follows that

$$
\infty = \sum_i \max(Y_i, N) \leq \sum_i Y_i
$$
a.s., QED.

Comment: The Lemma can be proved directly without invoking concepts like $\liminf$. Denote $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k$ and $A_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n y_k$. Note that $S_n = nA_n$. Since $A_n\rightarrow \mu>0$, therefore $S_n\rightarrow +\infty$.