# Are there nonlinear functions for which $\mathbb{E}[T(X)] = T(\mathbb{E}[X])$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, linear-transformations, expected-value

Consider a random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For a linear mapping $T: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have
$$\mathbb{E}[T(X)] = T(\mathbb{E}[X]).$$

I was wondering if there is an 'only iff' here, or whether there are mappings such that the relation still holds?
In particular, does the answer to the above question depend on the distribution and what would be the anser for e.g.  $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$?

Comment: If you have any symetric random variable $X$ with any moment, then obviously $\mathbb E[X^{2k+1}] = 0 = (\mathbb E[X])^{2k+1}$ (just an example)

Comment: Let $T$ be an *affine* map, noting that affine is not linear

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628386/321264