# Positive random variables with harmonic mean equal to mean have variance zero

Tags: probability, random-variables, means, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

Suppose $X>0$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{E}X=c$ and $\mathbb{E}X^{-1}=c^{-1}$.

By applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $\sqrt{X}$ and $\sqrt{X^{-1}}$ and using the "equality iff linearly dependent" case, we have that $X$ must be constant.

But this seems like far too heavy machinery for what ought to be an obvious statement. Is there a simpler proof? Is there an "equality iff" form of Jensen's inequality?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628386/when-jensens-inequality-is-equality?rq=1

Comment: @d.k.o. Though actually this doesn't take you all the way. If $X^{-1}=aX+b$, then there can be two positive solutions for $X$, so it may not be constant.