# Computing $E\left[\log\left(1 + \frac{\sum X_i}{n}\right)\right]$ when $X_i$ is iid $Geom\left(e^{-\lambda}\right)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, expected-value

Originally, I was attempting to find a Method of Moments estimator for $\lambda$ given $X_i \sim Geom(e^{-\lambda})$ s.t. $f_\lambda(x) = e^{-\lambda}(1 - e^{-\lambda})^x$.

I found it to be $\hat{\lambda} = \log\left(1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right)$.  I am now attempting to verify if it is unbiased ($E\left[\hat{\lambda}\right] \stackrel{?}{=} \lambda$). This leads to a super nasty summation:

$$
E\left[\log\left(1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right)\right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \log\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)\cdot 
\underbrace{\pmatrix{k + n - 1 \\ k} 
\cdot (1 - e^{-\lambda})^k e^{-n\lambda}}_\text{Negative binomial pmf}
$$

Note that $\sum X_i \sim NB(n, e^{-\lambda})$.

**My thoughts:** I am convinced that the sum is either divergent or not at all equal to $\lambda$.

- Are there any tools I could use to indirectly state this?
- Is there a feasible pen/paper way to calculate the exact sum or should this be left for something like Mathematica?

Comment: Aren't you missing some factors of $k$ and $n$ in your sum, like $(1-e^{-\lambda})^k e^{-n \lambda}$ instead of plain $(1-e^{-\lambda}) e^{- \lambda}$? These extra factors will make the sum better behaved.

Comment: Can you also state if the geometric random variable has support starting at $0$ or $1$?

Comment: You can use Jensen's inequality to check unbiasedness.

Comment: @user196574 yeah, I was fighting MathJax typing it out.  Support starts at 0.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I will try that out tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Without doing any calculations, I would expect the worst case to be when $n=1$ giving a finite expectation, and (given the non-linear function) for this to be biased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @StubbornAtom for suggesting Jensen's Inequality.  We know that $\log$ is concave thus it follows that $E[g(X)] \leq g(E[X])$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
E\left[\log\left(1 + \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right)\right] &\leq \log\left(E\left[1 + \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right]\right) \quad \text{(Jensen's Inequality)} \\
&=\log\left(1 + \dfrac{E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]}{n}\right) \quad \left(\text{Note: } \sum X_i \sim NB(n, e^{-\lambda} \right) \\
&=\log\left(1 + \dfrac{n\left(1 - e^{-\lambda}\right)/e^{-\lambda}}{n}\right) \\
&= \log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{e^{-\lambda}} - 1\right) \\
&= \log\left(e^{\lambda}\right) = \lambda
\end{aligned}
$$

This then implies that the original method of moments estimate $\hat{\lambda}$ is greater than, if not equal to, the RHS of the inequality.  For the equality to be true, our transformation must be [affine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1031498/966470) which I do not believe is true in this case (someone can correct me on that).

Thus, $\hat{\lambda}$ is a biased estimator of $\lambda$.